# Pre-Written android code throws nullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I dont know why this code throws a nullPointerException. I did not written this part of code and im pretty new with this staff. I tried my best but could not able to find an answer.

```
public class ProgramExamActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setTitle("Screen #1");
}
public void onClick(View v) {       
    switch(v.getId()) {     
        case R.id.btn2:
                setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
                setTitle("Screen #2");
                break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post Exception log.. with your question.

Comment: Logs can be more helpful for helpers :)

Comment: Although code written badly, With things which should be avoid.

Comment: propably its stupid question but where i can find log in eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

First, this

```
setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
setTitle("Screen #2");
```

you can't, you shouldn't call this more than once.

And second if you want to use `OnClickListener`, you need to register it for some `widget` and in your code there is any `widget`.

In your case your class need to implement `View.OnClickListener` if you don' want to work with *Listeners* as anonymous classes

```
public class Program... extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener { ... }
```

Then you need to register it like this:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

**Note:** if you want to start another `Activity` with different title and content, you have to use `Intents` and call `startActivity()`.

More about [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) and there is tutorial [Android: How to switch between Activities](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/).

Comment: @Enoras >> Yes well written answer, I would like to make one more point here,as Deceiver suggested not to set contentView twice . You Should actually start a new activity instead of setting new content view. and show your layout in new activity.

Comment: thanks for quick answer and link to tutorial. I tried to register, but it says that it have wrong tokens. I going to read all tutorials again, becouse i have feeling you waste your time with me.

Answer (score 0):

Add listener of click event as

```
public class ProgramExamActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
```

then, register your component with this listener. 
Suppose you want to add click on any of your Button like btn1.
then add code in OnCreate

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(ProgramExamActivity.this);
```

Comment: the same answer already given before 8 min, You should not post duplicate answer, if there is nothing new and unique in your answer Please avoid posting it.

Comment: Ok I marked and UPVOTED "deceiver"'s answer. It was my mistake that I have not read whole answer.